# Manage EntityManagerFactory in a web app

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, jdbc

I have developed an web app with GWT. I create only one EntityManagerFactory (singleton) but I don't know when I have to close it. I have followed the instructions of this web: http://javanotepad.blogspot.com/2007/05/jpa-entitymanagerfactory-in-web.html ,but after 8 hours without going into my application I have the error:

```
    78616509 [http-9080-Processor4] ERROR org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction - JDBC begin failed
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 44,115,64
4 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 44,115,644 milliseconds ago. is lo
nger than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing
 connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client tim
eouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1112)
```

After 2 or 3 attempts all works fine. If I close the EntityManagerFactory after each transaction I don't have problems, but I don't want to do that. I want know how can I manage the EntityManagerFactory cycle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The error message speak by it self

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 44,115,64 4
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   44,115,644 milliseconds ago. is lo nger than the server configured
>   value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
>   **testing  connection validity before use** in your application,
>   increasing the server configured values for client tim eouts, or using
>   the **Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true'** to avoid this
>   problem.

The recommend way is to use [c3p0 connection pool](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool) that manage expired connections.

> [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc)
>   Hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is, however, quite
>   rudimentary. It is intended to help you get started and is not
>   intended for use in a production system, or even for performance
>   testing. You should use a third party pool for best performance and
>   stability. Just replace the hibernate.connection.pool_size property
>   with connection pool specific settings. This will turn off Hibernate's
>   internal pool. For example, you might like to use c3p0.

In the MYSQL Reference documentation it is not recommended to use the `autoReconnect` property.

> [Connector/J autoReconnect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)
>   Should the driver try to re-establish stale and/or dead connections?
>   If enabled the driver will throw an exception for a queries issued on
>   a stale or dead connection, which belong to the current transaction,
>   but will attempt reconnect before the next query issued on the
>   connection in a new transaction. The use of this feature is not
>   recommended, because it has side effects related to session state and
>   data consistency when applications don't handle SQLExceptions
>   properly, and is only designed to be used when you are unable to
>   configure your application to handle SQLExceptions resulting from dead
>   and stale connections properly. Alternatively, investigate setting the
>   MySQL server variable "wait_timeout" to some high value rather than
>   the default of 8 hours.